# Dynamically assigning a class to a div tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline-code

I have a div where I swap out the background image on load when a button is clicked. But it loads the image specified in the css first then loads the image I tell it to in the  event. You can see this change of image as the page does a post back. Trying to reduce the "flicker" I decided to make 5 classes in my CSS and dynamically assign that class to the divs class tag. I made a class for each of the 5 image backgrounds. However it wont let me put inline code in the div. It doesn't like this line
`class="<%= strMenuButtonClass%>">`

```
<%
  //see which menu button was clicked
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------
  int menuButtonId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["buttonId"].ToString());
  string menuButtonClass = "divMasterCol1Button1";
  switch (menuButtonId){
  case 1:
      menuButtonClass = "divMasterCol1Button1";
      break;
  case 2:
      menuButtonClass = "divMasterCol1Button1";
      break;
  case 3:
      menuButtonClass = "divMasterCol1Button1";
      break;
  case 4:
      menuButtonClass = "divMasterCol1Button4";
      break;
  case 5:
      menuButtonClass = "divMasterCol1Button1";
      break;
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%>
```

And here is the div tag...

```html
<div id="divMasterCol1" class="<%= strMenuButtonClass%>">
        --content goes here--
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't that be <%= menuButtonClass%> ?

Comment: @Roto, you're attempting to change the `class` **attribute** of a `div` by assigning it a `string` **value**... for the sake of asking a better question, correct your terms: replace `class` with `string` - `class` and `string` are both **types** in **.Net**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

First, `strMenuButtonClass` is not the correct name. Should be `menuButtonClass`.

Secondly, `menuButtonClass` needs to be a public property or field in the C# code in order for the .aspx to see it.

```
public string menuButtonClass {get; set;}
```

Comment: **public property or field**.. or method... so pretty much just **public** (Accessor) anything..